# NPE when trying to read files from JAR

Tags: groovy, jar, nullpointerexception

When I try to read a directory inside the JAR using the following code:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream('/some-dir').text
```

I get a NPE with the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream.close(JarURLConnection.java:108)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implClose(StreamDecoder.java:378)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.close(StreamDecoder.java:193)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.close(InputStreamReader.java:199)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.close(BufferedReader.java:525)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport.closeWithWarning(DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.getText(IOGroovyMethods.java:892)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.getText(IOGroovyMethods.java:835)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$833.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.doMethodInvoke(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
    at com.blabla.Main.test(Main.groovy:68)
    at com.blabla.Main.main(Main.groovy:78)
```

Curiously the exception is only thrown when executing the JAR. When executing it from the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) it works fine.

Comment: Is the resource in the jar?  Sounds like it's ok when intellij can see all the files, but it's missing from the jar file when it's created

Comment: @tim_yates It is. Oddly the exception is when closing the input stream.